# Imagelist add image can't save

Tags: c#, save, imagelist

I have an imagelist Large Icon (i added 64 image manuel) and my code success add image to my imagelist but can't save. If Form close and rebuild then not listed my added image. How to save my added image to imagelist?

```
imageList.Images.Add(someImage);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not meant to work afaik.

You need to **re-add** them each time.

You would have to somehow add them to the exe (or a dll), meaning **re-compiling** it during runtime .. Tough stuff.

Add the image to an application folder or maybe to a [zip file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to keep them in on one handy file; re-add them all upon start-up!

Comment: I understand. Thanks.